# value not saving in database and error cannot implicitly convert type infragistics.win.ultrawingrid to decimal

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultracombo

Hello How are you Friends.

i want to save data  using grid after entering data when i press save button then data not saving in database i am sharing code please Anyone resolve this problem.

These lines are giving error

```
objInvDetail.mQty_Out = this.cmbGodownFrom.SelectedRow; 
objInvDetail.mQty = this.cmbGoDownTo.SelectedRow;
```

Error is  **cannot implicitly convert type `infragistics.win.ultrawingrid` to `decimal`**

Here is My View
[Winform Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCecZ.png)

```
 public override void mSave()
    {
        try
        {
            if (mValidate())
            {
                objInvDetail.mQty_Out = this.cmbGodownFrom.SelectedRow;
                objInvDetail.mQty = this.cmbGoDownTo.SelectedRow;

                if (mAddNewRec)
                {
                    objclsInvMain.mSaveInvoiceMain(objInvMain, myDT, "", InvmainSave);
                    mInitializeData();
                }
                else
                    objclsInvMain.mSaveInvoiceMain(objInvMain, myDT, "", InvmainSave);

                mAddNewRec = false;
                mModifyRec = false;
                mLockControls(true);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, DAL.clsCommon.mModuleName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Share your DetailsView definition. You cannot directly assign the SelectedRow.

Comment: i have enter a winform pic you can see image.

Comment: tanveer-badar bro please give skype id i ll show you in detail .

Comment: The `SelectedRow`contains an entire row, you cannot assign that to a single field like `mQty_Out'`You should assign the selected value from the combobox instead

Comment: I already bind combobox with Selectedvalue and DisplayValue you can see in imgae i have attached .

Answer (score 0):

This line has an error, like you say.

`objInvDetail.mQty = this.cmbGoDownTo.SelectedRow;`

Is there any SelectedValue available for the combobox so you can write the following instead?

`objInvDetail.mQty = this.cmbGoDownTo.SelectedValue;`

Comment: I use SelectedValue but giving me error Ultracombo does not contain the definition for SelectedValue and no extension method SelectedValue

Comment: isma can you give me skype id .

Comment: Use the chat for that. :P

Comment: i just need your 2 mint , i am not taking your much time .

Comment: i think when i will show you in Detail you could better understand and Suggest me Solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

```
objInvDetail.mQty = this.cmbGoDownTo.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: dear ultracombo not supported selecteditem , problem resolve when i write .value

Answer (score 0):

Try using

var activeRow = yourGrid.ActiveRow to get the active row and then

activeRow.Cells("Stock").Value.ToString() to get the value of the cell.

Hope this helps :)